# When you add a new value to a dictionary, is it stored by value or refrence?

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that takes a string and a list of strings. I am trying to add values for my list with a loop, add my list to my dictionary then clear my list and use it again for the next item in my dictionary. However when I clear my list it seems to clear the list in my Dictionary as well, This leads me to believe the list in the dictionary is stored as a reference to my list, is this correct?, If so what data types are stores by reference and what are stored by value? Heres my code:

```
foreach (var item in fileDictionary)
            {

                foreach (var file in fileArray)
                {
                    if (!Array.Exists(item.Value, element => element.Contains(file + today)))
                    {
                        tempFileList.Add(file + today);
                    }
                }
                resultDictionary.Add(item.Key, tempFileList);
               tempFileList.Clear();
            }
```

Is there a way I can store this list by value in my dictionary?  If not is there a better approach to initializing a new array for every iteration of my loop?

Comment: Just Wondering, is there a consensus on weather it is better to clone the list  or declare a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always stored by value.  However, when the type is a *reference* type (which both `Array` and `List<T>` are), the value IS a reference.  So anything you do using one reference affects the underlying object, which is reflected in the reference stored in the dictionary.

> Is there a way I can store this list by value in my dictionary?

I think what you really want is to store a *copy* of the list in the dictionary, so you can manipulate it without affecting the list that was stored.  The simplest way to do that is just to make a shallow clone of the list using the copy constructor:

```
resultDictionary.Add(item.Key, new List<{type}>(tempFileList));
```

Answer (score 4):

List is reference type, no matter where you save it. In your case, you should not clear the tempFileList at all. just declare a new one inside your loop

```
        foreach (var item in fileDictionary)
        {
            var tempFileList = fileArray
               .Where(file => !Array.Exists(item.Value, element => element.Contains(file + today))
               .Select(file => file + today)
               .ToList();

            resultDictionary.Add(item.Key, tempFileList);

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the type `TValue` of your `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`:

- When `TValue`, such as in your case, is a class, it is stored by reference.
- When `TValue` is a `struct`, which includes primitive types of .NET, then it is stored by value.

**Note:** I am sure that you have figured out that your problem can be solved by replacing `tempFileList.Clear()` with `tempFileList = new List<string>()`, but I'll mention it here anyway for users who come to this site because they experience the same problem.

Comment: List is a reference type regardless of its item type.

Comment: The fact that you're making a distinction between the behavior of a list stored in a dictionary for different types of TValue. There isn't one. It doesn't matter if it is a Dictionary<string, List<int>> or a Dictionary<string, List<object>>. Unless you care to elaborate and demonstrate the difference between something "stored by reference" vs "stored by value", it isn't clear what your answer is getting at.

Comment: My mistake. Somehow my addled mind saw List in your Dictionary when it wasn't there

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is not a primitive type (int, boolean, char, ...) is always passed as reference in C#. This means you cant store your list by value. But you can add a copy of your list to your Map. This way, if you clear the original one, you wont touch the one in your Map.
To copy a list you can use:

```
List<string> copyOfMyList = new List<string>(myList);
```

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading, as there are plenty of value types that aren't defined as primitives in the .NET Framework.